# Microsoft OAuth 2.0: Account unavailable error.

Tags: outlook, oauth-2.0, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to authenticate my application using Microsoft OAuth 2.0. Application registration is already done.

I'm using a web browser component to make user allow the application to access user's calendars. Then I'm tracking the redirection URLs to extract the authorization code. 
But the service redirects the application to an error page.

The URLs: (My application navigates user to the first URL containing authentication info)

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_mode=form_post&prompt=login&client_id=c36b4fd4-8b5a-4831-b146-6e4cdac90d0e&scope=https:%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fcalendars.readwrite &response_type=code&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
about:blank
https://login.live.com/Me.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&idpflag=direct&wreply=https:%2F%2Flogin.microsoftonline.com
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?response_mode=form_post&prompt=login&client_id=c36b4fd4-8b5a-4831-b146-6e4cdac90d0e&scope=https:%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fcalendars.readwrite &response_type=code&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&login_hint=altostratous%40outlook.com&ui_locales=en-US&display=page&uaid=1ed5dd7edad547ea9ae42599ecf8028e&issuer=mso&msproxy=1
https://login.live.com/ppsecure/post.srf?response_mode=form_post&prompt=login&client_id=c36b4fd4-8b5a-4831-b146-6e4cdac90d0e&scope=https:%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fcalendars.readwrite &response_type=code&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&login_hint=altostratous%40outlook.com&ui_locales=en-US&display=page&issuer=mso&msproxy=1&contextid=04C5394112425BED&bk=1466075419&uaid=1ed5dd7edad547ea9ae42599ecf8028e&pid=15216
https://account.live.com/Consent/Update?ru=https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf%3flc%3d1033%26response_mode%3dform_post%26prompt%3dlogin%26client_id%3dc36b4fd4-8b5a-4831-b146-6e4cdac90d0e%26scope%3dhttps%253A%252F%252Fgraph.microsoft.com%252Fcalendars.readwrite%2520%26response_type%3dcode%26redirect_uri%3durn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob%26login_hint%3daltostratous%2540outlook.com%26ui_locales%3den-US%26display%3dpage%26issuer%3dmso%26msproxy%3d1%26uaid%3d1ed5dd7edad547ea9ae42599ecf8028e%26pid%3d15216%26mkt%3dEN-US%26scft%3dDevbhujhpkAjAfbj!ZXBlvEp*4p0KUzdBN3n1IHXrQQauBhA50taNhaXBRiw83xqwtX5hxg4gWMoeOwyjHM8Rh7ou9Ho!Zxun*eKSj3YFvrDeYTKWi5Ch!tAwgEuey7KPwCE22PPek0hBJ23YxeB!zqgG8pviIyWCDZED!86SBSE%26contextid%3d04C5394112425BED&mkt=EN-US&uiflavor=web&id=293577&client_id=000000004019AB47&rd=none&scope=calendars.readwrite&cscope=
https://c1.microsoft.com/c.gif?DI=4050&did=1&t=
https://account.live.com/Consent/Update?ru=https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf%3flc%3d1033%26response_mode%3dform_post%26prompt%3dlogin%26client_id%3dc36b4fd4-8b5a-4831-b146-6e4cdac90d0e%26scope%3dhttps%253A%252F%252Fgraph.microsoft.com%252Fcalendars.readwrite%2520%26response_type%3dcode%26redirect_uri%3durn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob%26login_hint%3daltostratous%2540outlook.com%26ui_locales%3den-US%26display%3dpage%26issuer%3dmso%26msproxy%3d1%26uaid%3d1ed5dd7edad547ea9ae42599ecf8028e%26pid%3d15216%26mkt%3dEN-US%26scft%3dDevbhujhpkAjAfbj!ZXBlvEp*4p0KUzdBN3n1IHXrQQauBhA50taNhaXBRiw83xqwtX5hxg4gWMoeOwyjHM8Rh7ou9Ho!Zxun*eKSj3YFvrDeYTKWi5Ch!tAwgEuey7KPwCE22PPek0hBJ23YxeB!zqgG8pviIyWCDZED!86SBSE%26contextid%3d04C5394112425BED&mkt=EN-US&uiflavor=web&id=293577&client_id=000000004019AB47&rd=none&scope=calendars.readwrite&cscope=
https://login.live.com/ppsecure/post.srf?lc=1033&response_mode=form_post&prompt=login&client_id=c36b4fd4-8b5a-4831-b146-6e4cdac90d0e&scope=https:%2f%2fgraph.microsoft.com%2fcalendars.readwrite+&response_type=code&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&login_hint=altostratous%40outlook.com&ui_locales=en-US&display=page&issuer=mso&msproxy=1&mkt=EN-US&scft=DevbhujhpkAjAfbj!ZXBlvEp*4p0KUzdBN3n1IHXrQQauBhA50taNhaXBRiw83xqwtX5hxg4gWMoeOwyjHM8Rh7ou9Ho!Zxun*eKSj3YFvrDeYTKWi5Ch!tAwgEuey7KPwCE22PPek0hBJ23YxeB!zqgG8pviIyWCDZED!86SBSE&contextid=04C5394112425BED&bk=1466075521&uaid=1ed5dd7edad547ea9ae42599ecf8028e&pid=15216&fsui=1
```

The pages:

First it asks user to log in:
[image: First it asks user to log in.]

Then asks the user to allow the application.

[image: Then asks the user to allow the application.]

At last this error page is shown when user accepts.

[image: At last this error page is shown.]

Comment: Can you confirm that this account has been upgraded to the new Outlook.com experience. Quick way to tell is if you're able to install any Outlook add-ins to your account.

Comment: I'll check that but do you mean that access to calendars is only allowed for outlook accounts that are upgraded. If so how to upgrade my account?

Comment: The update will happen automatically. Users are being updated over time (there are a lot of mailboxes and migration at that scale takes time). You can read about the new Outlook.com at https://blogs.office.com/2016/02/17/OUTLOOK-COM-OUT-OF-PREVIEW-AND-BETTER-THAN-EVER/

Comment: I created a new outlook account but it resulted in the same error. Although the account is upgraded and I'm able to add add-ins to my outlook inbox, it doesn't work.